# Views Error - Views folder is empty

Tags: views, backups

I have a drupal site on remote server.
The site is working properly right now.

I just check and the views folder is empty!!

I looked into the ftp, and also on the remote server it looks like the views folder is empty.
The site works perfect currently with many views, but it looks like the views folder under public_html/sites/all/modules/views is empty.

When I checked the permission it say "0711". and it says that owner can read edit and everything..

How that can be that I see empty folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full restore did not work](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110265/full-restore-did-not-work)

Comment: It is not. It is different question. Only on the views folder, and the reason ir is empty on remote server.. Even when the site works perfect now. Is it permissions?

Comment: @AnilSagar this is totally a different question. Can you please make it live again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the views folder was on the ROOT/modules folder, and not on the ROOT/sites/all/modules folder.